# Only True Pokemon Fans Will Be Able to Solve This! [2nd Edition]

Tags: rebus

How well do you know these popular Pokemon across several generations??? Some of them might be easier and others harder, but the important thing is that you have fun! Enjoy!

[image]

Comment: Are you sure E isn't missing a part?

Comment: The last part of the clue is not the full version of e, but I thought it would be enough to answer the clue! :)

Comment: Sorry, I meant rebus E.

Comment: Oh, you are correct, good catch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A.

> Laptop - top + Pras = **Lapras**. (found by hagfy)

B.

> Vial + Pluto - toe + meme? = **Vileplume**.

C.

> Bid + Goof - G = **Bidoof**.­­­

D.

> O + nicks = **Onix**.

E.

> Arrow + Dakota - ota = **Aerodactyl**.

F.

> Geo + Dude = **Geodude**.

G.

> Poo + Chi + Anna = **Poochyena**.

H.

> Clay + fair + $e$ = **Clefairy**.

Comment: Good job, those are correct so far! @noadne

Comment: @noedne You can take my A. answer to round out your post.  I only posted separately because I also had an (incorrect) answer to D, which you sniped anyway.  =)

Comment: @hagfy Thanks! I saw your other answer and thought it fit well enough to wonder whether the switch was supposed to be flipped the other way, as they can certainly be misread.

Comment: @oMiKeY Please use comments to give constructive suggestions for improvement.

Comment: if you had read my comment you would realize your B is wrong, for the reason i mentioned in my comment.

Comment: @oMiKeY Could you please reiterate it? I did not see a reason when I read it.

Answer (score 4):

A.

> Laptop - top + Pras = Lapras